# Collections sort not being accepted by Eclipse

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import com.javaranch.common.TextFileIn;

    public class SortNames 
    {
        public static class CelebrityNamesFile
        {
            public String firstName;
            public String lastName;

            public static class CompareLastName implements Comparator< CelebrityNamesFile >
            {
                @Override
                public int compare( CelebrityNamesFile o1,  CelebrityNamesFile o2 )
                {
                    return o2.lastName.compareTo( o1.lastName );
                }
            }

        public static void main( String[ ] args ) throws IOException
        {

            ArrayList< CelebrityNamesFile > myCelebrityList;
            myCelebrityList = new ArrayList< CelebrityNamesFile >();

            TextFileIn celebrityNamesFile = new TextFileIn( "celebrityNamesFile.txt" );
            boolean doneReadingCelebrityNames = false;
            while ( ! doneReadingCelebrityNames )
            {
                 String oneName = celebrityNamesFile.readLine();
                 if ( oneName == null )
                 {
                     doneReadingCelebrityNames = true;
                 }
```

$
Eclipse doesn't like the add statement that follows, to wit: *The method add (SortNames.CelebrityNamesFile) in the type ArrayList(SortNames.CelebrityNamesFile)is not applicable for the arguments (String)*

```
                 else
                 {
                     myCelebrityList.add( oneName );
                 }
            }
            celebrityNamesFile.close();
```

$
And then it doesn't like my sort statement, to wit:
*Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List T) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList (SortNames.CelebrityNamesFile)). The inferred type SortNames.CelebrityNamesFile is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter (T extends Comparable(? super T))*

```
            Collections.sort( myCelebrityList );
            System.out.println( myCelebrityList );

            Collections.sort( myCelebrityList, new CelebrityNamesFile.CompareLastName() );
            System.out.println( myCelebrityList );
}
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?  I have read many posts here, have read the Java docs regarding comparator, have read Java tutorials regarding comparator.  Head First Java, Ivor Horton's beginning Java 7. Still clueless.

The purpose of the program is to read names from a txt file, add them to an arraylist, print the arraylist in its natural order, sort the arraylist by last name, print the list again.

Comment: Instead of writing prose commentary interrupting your code, you should use a single block of properly code that can be copy-pasted into an IDE, and point out the important lines with comments. (Also, drop the `import`s, they just obecure the code.) If you need longer prose, refer to the lines you pointed out previously.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the first issue, the problem is fairly simple. `oneName` is a `String`, and `myCelebrityList` is a collection of `CelebrityNamesFile`- which means that you can only add objects to the collection of type `CelebrityNamesFile`.

For the second issue, your problem is that the `CelebrityNamesFile` class does not implement the `Comparable` interface. Sorting requires that an ordering is implemented for the list element type, e.g. by implementing `Comparable` for the class or providing a `Comparator` to the `sort`.

Comment: +1 Good answer... for a newbie :) Welcome to SO! btw, it should implement `Comparable<CelebrityNamesFile>` - since 1.5, `Comparable` is typed

Comment: Yes, that's one method, but check that OP has already implemented a Comparator.

Comment: I did notice that, but I feel that simple telling someone to use the explicit comparator version of the function doesn't explain the error message :)

Answer (score 2):

For first issue, you're trying to add a `String` into a `List<CelebrityNamesFile>` instance. You sould use the String to create a `CelebrityNamesFile` instance and add this instance to your list:

```
CelebrityNamesFile celebrityNamesFile = new CelebrityNamesFile();
celebrityNamesFile.lastName = oneName;
myCelebrityList.add( celebrityNamesFile );
```

For second issue, try

```
Collections.sort(myCelebrityList, new CompareLastName());
```

As @alyu points, the `CelebrityNamesFile` class needs to implement the `Comparable` interface to work with the code you're posting, but you could also add a `Comparator<CelebrityNamesFile>` instance (and you already have the `CompareLastName` class that implements it).

More about this:

- [Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 1):

1. You're trying to add a `String` (the object `oneName`) to a list of `CelebrityNamesFile`s. You need to somehow create a `CelebrityNamesFile` out of this `String`.
2. `Collections.sort()` only works on objects that are `Comparable` if you don't explicitly pass a comparator. Try this instead:

   `Collections.sort(myCelebrityList, new CelebrityNamesFile.CompareLastName());`

Answer (score 1):

The collection `myCelebrityList` is of type `CelebrityNamesFile` and that means it can only accept instances of that class. You need to create an instance of `CelebrityNamesFile` and add it to the collection. The `Collections` wont accept your collection because you class `CelebrityNamesFile` does not implement the `Comparator` interface. You need to pass your comparator instance to the `Collections.sort()` as second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `Comparator` implemented in the `CompareLastName` class can be put outside the `SortNames` class, or at least outside the `CelebrityNamesFile` class.  I was having the exact same issue until I put the class that implements my Comparator outside of my object class.  After I did this, the program worked perfectly.  Here's a sample of my code with comments if it helps.

```
// Comparator interface for my Word Class.
public interface Comparator<Word>
{ 
    int compare(Word first, Word second); 
}

// Word Class, which is my object.
public class Word
{
    private String word;
    public Word(String input)  { word = input; }
    public String get()  { return word; }
    public int wordSize()  { return word.length(); }
}

// Comparator implementation is separate from my Word Class.
public class WordComparator implements Comparator<Word>
{
    public int compare(Word first, Word second)
    {
        if (first.wordSize() < second.wordSize())  { return -1; }
        else if (first.wordSize() > second.wordSize())  { return 1; }
        else  { return first.get().compareTo(second.get()); }
    }
}

// Now run the program to ensure the Word Class objects and the WordComparator
// Class are implemented correctly.
public class WordComparatorDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Word> list = new ArrayList<Word>();
        JFileChooser find = new JFileChooser();
        Scanner read = null;
        if(find.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File selectedFile = find.getSelectedFile();
            read = new Scanner(selectedFile);
            try
            {
                list = inputData(read);
                // Here's the sort implementing the WordComparator.
                Collections.sort(list, new WordComparator());
            }
            finally  { read.close(); }
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList<Word> inputData(Scanner in)
    {
        ArrayList<Word> list = new ArrayList<Word>();
        in.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]+");
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            String word = in.next();
            Word temp = new Word(word);
            list.add(temp);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Note: My answer is a year after the original post, but hopefully it will help anyone who visits this site for help.